# Reading/Monitoring Direct Memory Address Java

Tags: java, memory

I've been doing research, and I'm not 100% sure it's possible to do what I want using Java.
I'm writing a program that is supposed to use a memory location from another program, track the value at that memory location, and use that value for checks on events. (IE: other program value == 400, my program plays a noise).

I have ways of getting the hex value of the memory location, though if possible, I'd like to directly write my own code to do so in my Java applet.

Is there a library I can use to do either of these things?

For those who play League of Legends, precisely what I'm trying to do is track the amount of gold you currently have, and when your gold amount matches the cost of selected items, the program makes a noise. I can locate the location of the gold counter for League in memory by back-tracing the initial value and then the value after buying a health or mana pot.

Comment: Java runs inside a JVM, it does not have access to system memory outside of that allocated to the JVM. You can use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to call a `C` or `C++` binary that _can_ access arbitrary memory, but this is fairly involved.

Comment: Can I use JNI and create an applet with the same code?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I had read that implementing C/C++ code into Java makes it so that you can no longer run as an executable JAR, which was why I was avoiding that method to begin with.

Comment: That is the whole point. If you want the portability of Java, you **have** to run solely within the JVM and not poke around outside. If you want to poke around outside of the JVM you immediately become platform dependant, and you loose all the portability that Java offers.

Comment: That was exactly the answer I was looking for.
Thank you so much.